# Wordpress ecommerce site and Android Studio app integration

Tags: android, wordpress, api, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have developed an ecommerce website using WordPress. Now m planning to build an app for it through Android studio but my concern is how will my website and app integrate? Is there any bar on technology to be used while creating an app for wordpress ecommerce website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there are two ways to do it.
1.If you do not have any coding knowledge then you can hire an app developer or you can convert your website into app by outsourcing to the app-builders of course it wont be for free you will have to pay.

2. If you are having the coding knowledge, then the first thing you need to choose is the framework. I would recommend ionic framework and you can add the woo-commerce API into the ionic framework. You will have to design the app as per your requirement, however you get the products of your store through API.

Comment: ionic framework is a cross platform i.e., you can build app for both android OS as well as IOS. You dont need to code separately.